# How can I tell which project I'm using in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

I often have multiple copies of the same Git repository on my machine. I usually have multiple Sublime Text windows open, each with the opened project for one of the Git repo copies.

Is there any setting that will show the project file's path on the status or title bar, or some other way of easily distinguishing otherwise similar projects from each other? As it is, I have no easy way of distinguishing which Sublime Text window is using which project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title bar of Sublime will show you the file name portion of the project currently associated with a window by default; it's the text to the right of the name of the currently selected file inside round brackets. For example, here I have the `OverrideAudit` project currently open:

[image: Sample window caption]

There's no way (currently) to display other information in the caption bar, but using some plugin code you can display text in the status bar instead.

[Edit] There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1179) on the issue tracker to add the ability to configure the title bar which you may want to weigh in on. [/Edit]

Here is an example of a plugin that replicates putting the project name from the window caption into the status bar. If desired you could modify the code in `show_project` that isolates only the project name to e.g. include the path if desired.

To use this, you can select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu and replace the default stub with this code, modifying as needed.

This code is [also available on GitHub](https://github.com/OdatNurd/SublimeScraps/blob/master/plugins/project_in_statusbar.py).

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os

# Related Reading:
#     https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/displaying-project-name-on-the-rite-side-of-the-status-bar/24721

# This just displays the filename portion of the current project file in the
# status bar, which is the same text that appears by default in the window
# caption.

def plugin_loaded ():
    """
    Ensure that all views in all windows show the associated project at startup.
    """
    # Show project in all views of all windows
    for window in sublime.windows ():
        for view in window.views ():
            show_project (view)

def show_project(view):
    """
    If a project file is in use, add the name of it to the start of the status
    bar.
    """
    if view.window() is None:
        return

    project_file = view.window ().project_file_name ()
    if project_file is not None:
        project_name = os.path.splitext (os.path.basename (project_file))[0]
        view.set_status ("00ProjectName", "[" + project_name + "]")

class ProjectInStatusbar(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """
    Display the name of the current project in the status bar.
    """
    def on_new(self, view):
        show_project (view)

    def on_load(self, view):
        show_project (view)

    def on_clone(self, view):
        show_project (view)
```